# Avoiding stranding/Stopping AccuRev update from removing folders from old Stream

Tags: accurev

Here's the situation...

We have work involving a Phase1 stream and Phase2 stream.
Both have the same parent.
But, changes from Phase1 can't yet be promoted. (Obviously, there will be multiple devs working in Phase2)
As the names suggest, Phase2 work requires changes from Phase1.

So, right now I what I tried was... Be in Phase1 stream, get the new code, KEEP it... Change to Phase2 and update whenever needed - Didn't work.

The issue is that I can KEEP the files but there are some new folders which I can't make AccuRev to retain. But, maybe even KEEPing them won't help, as I've changed the stream, and stranding would happen.

Is there any solution to this?
I could use some cumbersome copy-paste method as the last resort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO, you should have the Phase2 stream based off Phase1 stream.  This is the logical/easiest solution since Phase2 requires changes from Phase1.

Since your are not doing this, I would create a stream off of Phase2 and cross promote the changes from Phase1 you want to include in Phase2.  This will eliminate the cumbersome process/problems you are encountering above.

Comment: Thanks. I was guessing such a re-structuring would be the AccuRev way of getting it done.

But, it'd have been great if there was any way for AccuRev to treat those changes just as other changes (That's how the copy-paste method worked).